# how to extract index value and element value from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains the following,

```
                   Reading
Date                        
2020-05-09 14:54:00    13661
2020-05-09 14:55:00    13672
2020-05-09 14:56:00    14251
2020-05-09 14:59:00    15255
```

I have figured out how to extract the last element:

lastelement=(series["Reading"].iloc[-1])

which gives me "15255"

Note:the first column is the index not a column in the dataframe as such.

so I also want to extract the index value for that same element (which may not be unique int the readings column), i.e. "2020-05-09 14:59:00"

I can anybody help?

thanks

(forgive me if my question is poor, its my first post on stackoverflow! - I can usually work my answers out from all of the other questions/answers presented here)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`df.tail()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html):

```
df.tail(1)
```

If you only want the index value, you can add:

```
df.tail(1).index.values
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:-

```
data = [['2020-05-09 14:54:00', 13661],
        ['2020-05-09 14:55:00', 15255],
        ['2020-05-09 14:55:00', 13672],
        ['2020-05-09 14:56:00', 15255],
        ['2020-05-09 14:56:00', 14251],
        ['2020-05-09 14:59:00', 15255]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Date","Reading"])
df.set_index("Date",inplace=True)
last_element=df.Reading[len(df)-1]
last_element_indices = list(df[df["Reading"]==last_element].index.tolist())
print("Last Element :",last_element)
print("Indices :", last_element_indices)
```

Expected Output:-

```
Last Element : 15255
Indices : ['2020-05-09 14:55:00', '2020-05-09 14:56:00', '2020-05-09 14:59:00']
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the dataframe to the filtered value, [squeeze](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) it to get a boolean array, and index the index to get your values :

```
df.index[df.eq(df.iloc[-1]).squeeze()]

Index(['2020-05-09 14:55:00', '2020-05-09 14:56:00', '2020-05-09 14:59:00'], dtype='object', name='Date')
```

Answer (score -1):

For reading and index exact value.

Try:

```
df.tail(1).Reading.values[0]
df.tail(1).Date.values[0]
```